# How to exclude a directory while doing multiple read?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in python and i am trying to read through a path all the files in the directories and sub-directories and combine the relevant ones in a single file. At the same time i want to exclude some specific sub-directories and i am getting stuck at this step. Appreciate any help from the experts !!

Here are some details

Main path:

```
/usr/home/micro/**/*.txt
```

Sub-directory to be skipped:

```
 /usr/home/micro/frame/test
```

My Python code so far

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys
import glob

complete = glob.glob('/usr/home/micro/**/*.txt', recursive=True) 

def test():
    with open("results.txt", "w") as f:
        for name in complete:
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/usr/home/micro/frame/"):
                for skipped in ("/usr/home/micro/frame/test"):
                    if skipped in dirs:
                        dirs.remove(skipped)
            with open(name) as currentfile:
                current = currentfile.read()
                    f.write(current)

def main ():
    test()

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just skip the name that starts with your path:

```
def test():
    with open("results.txt", "w") as f:
        for name in complete:
            if name.startswith("/usr/home/micro/frame/test"):
                continue
            with open(name) as currentfile:
                current = currentfile.read()
                    f.write(current)
```

No need for `os.walk` if already us `glob.glob`.

Comment: This worked beautifully and is way simple to implement.

Thank you all the experts for your help !!

Answer (score 1):

The `for skipped in ("/usr/home/micro/frame/test"):` line doesn't do what you think it does. It isn't iterating over a tuple, but rather over the characters of your single path.

You need a comma just before the end of the parentheses to make it a tuple: `("/usr/home/micro/frame/test",)`. Without the comma, the parentheses are just an unnecessary order of operations hint (like how `(2*2)+1` is the same as `2*2+1`). Alternatively, if you're only ever going to have the one path to exclude, you could get rid of the loop entirely.

That won't fix your code by itself, since you aren't actually doing anything useful in the `os.walk` loop other than trying to exclude the unwanted folder. But if you got rid of the loop on `complete` and used the `files` iterable from `os.walk`, you'd be able to do what I think you want.

Try something like this:

```
def test():
    with open("results.txt", "w") as f:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/usr/home/micro/frame/"):   # get rid of first loop
            for skipped in ("/usr/home/micro/frame/test",):       # add comma to make a tuple
                if skipped in dirs:
                    dirs.remove(skipped)
            for name in files:           # move the rest of the logic inside the os.walk loop
                fullname = os.path.join(root, name)
                with open(fullname) as currentfile:
                    current = currentfile.read()
                f.write(current)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears names of directories to be skipped is in "/usr/home/micro/frame/test" file. Then you need to read this file to a list and use that list:

```
with open("skipfilenames.txt", "r") as f:
    skiplist = f.read().splitlines()
```

Then you can use:

```
for skipped in skiplist:
...
```